# Is Helly's Theorem incorrectly stated in the book GTM 261, Probability and Stochastics?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to confirm my observation that Helly's Theorem is improperly stated.[image]

The attached image is P.96 of the book "Probability and Stochastics, GTM 261".

It seems that the author has overlooked the issue of
"Escape of Measure". The limiting function $c$ needs not be a cumulative distribution function (in the sense: increasing, right-continuous, $\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty} c(t)=0$, and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} c(t)=1$.)

Counter-example, let $c_n(t) = 1_{[n,\infty)} (t)$.
Then $c_n(t)\rightarrow 0$ pointwisely. Therefore, no matter what subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ is chosen, the limiting function $c(t)$ is constant zero, which is NOT a c.d.f. in the above sense.

Comment: Any chance you can transcribe the image? It's [more useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) because not everyone can read images. For example, I'm on a mobile device right now and text would be easier for me to read.

Comment: This definition of "distribution function" requires neither $\lim_{t \to -\infty} c(t) = 0$ nor  $\lim_{t \to +\infty} c(t) = 1$.  So the constant $0$ is, indeed, allowed.

Comment: The author stated that it is in "probabilistic terrain".
Moreover, I notice the range of distribution function is $[0,1]$.
Therefore I assume that "distribution function" refers to c.d.f. of a probability measure.